# Using Django and Tornado IOLoops

Tags: python, django, tornado

I'm trying to figure out the best way to integrate my Django app running on a uWSGI server with a Tornado IOLoop, I'm trying to use the queue feature from Tornado, but I don't want to go as far as to switch servers.

I understand Django is supposed to be stateless therefore my doubt is where to store the instance of Tornado.IOLoop that is consuming a certain queue.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Because, using asynchronous Tornado code in synchronous Django code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'm trying to shoot events to a pub/sub but I don't want to wait on them synchronously, I got a proof of concept working, however this same code doesn't run when I mix Django and Celery

Comment: But if you're using Celery already, if I remember correctly it provides asynchronous task execution from the box, so why not just use Django+Celery without Tornado.IOLoop? I didn't mean, that Tornado won't work with Django, I meant, that if you just put Tornado inside the Django app, the Django code will still block when it's in control, because it's synchronous, though I believe using threads this can be improved. Also, if you have a proof of concept, you might want to include it in the question, this will help others help you with the question.

Comment: @Nikita thanks for the suggestions, I'm only trying to fix the tornado loop because of this library https://github.com/nats-io/python-nats I ended up doing an entire different thing, setting up an RPC endpoint to publish events